# Как подключить библиотеку к файлу формата .js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Требуется подключить библиотеки jquery, GMap.js в файл MyScript.js (Формальное название для примера). Дело в том что все эти скрипты в html документе выглядят не очень красиво и легко путаешься, хотелось бы вынести пару троек скриптов и подключать и подгружать их. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В JS нет возможности сделать import. Как вариант, можно исходный код одного js-файла залить в другой. Но нужно быть осторожным, чтобы не было одинаковых глобальных переменных и названий функций.

Comment: @LEQADA, ну зачем так категорично. Есть же require.js, browserify, webpack и много других хитрых штук.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, добавил в комментарий один обходной вариант в лоб. Но это всё же кастыль.

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того, что именно подразумевается под "эти скрипты в html документе выглядят не очень" Если вы прямо вставляете текст скрипта - то это неправильный выбор, следует делать так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="урл к файлу js"></script>
```

http://htmlbook.ru/html/script

Учитывайте, что загрузка скрипта останавливает основной поток, поэтому либо ставьте их в конце `<body />` (но внутри) либо с параметром `async`.

---

Если же все-таки вы это знаете, но вам хочется динамически загружать скрипты из своего, то для этого можно либо воспользоваться библиотеками, например [Require.JS](http://requirejs.org/) или самому написать вот такое:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    // Скрипт был загружен
};

document.head.appendChild(script);
script.src = 'урл к вашему файлу';
```

Есть еще один путь, т.к. у вас **jQuery** - ее можно использовать в качестве загрузчика - у нее есть такой функционал:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  // Загрузили
});
```

---

Т.к. у вас несколько скриптов, необходимо их загружать с учетом зависимостей.

В jQuery можно сделать так:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "script1.js" ),
    $.getScript( "script2.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){
    // все загрузили
});
```