# чем заменить src в теге <script>

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

у меня есть такой код:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vkontakte/vk-bridge@2.0.8/dist/index.umd.js"></script>
<script>
//тут используется выше подключенная библиотека
</script>
```

Возможно ли как-то подключать эту библиотеку прямо из тэга script? По типу вот так:

```
<script>
import https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@vkontakte/vk-bridge@2.0.8/dist/index.umd.js; // вот типо такого должно быть
//тут используется выше подключенная библиотека
</script>
```

Comment: Сохрани библиотеку локально на своём сайте и импортируй как хочешь. С удалённого хоста вроде не поддерживается импорт.

Comment: @xmikex нашёл решение : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468858/Как-подключить-библиотеку-к-файлу-формата-js